# Apache Cordova and Sencha Touch 2.3

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, cordova-3

I am facing difficulties in creating custom plugin in apache cordova and use in sencha touch 2.3.1. Where we have to define javascript interface is not mention in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the cordova version you should not need to add it to Sencha Touch, if your plugman compatible plugin works correct, as it will be added with the cordova-plugin.js file.

But in case you are having trouble with that way you can add it insdie the app.json file.

```
"js": [
        {
            "path": "YourPluginJSFile.js",
            "remote": true
        },
        {
            "path": "cordova.js",
            "remote": true
        },
```